# Why after migrating angular from 8 to 9 i'm getting exceeded maximum budget on scss files

Tags: angular, angular-builder, angularbuild, angular-migration

I migrated my Angular project from 8 to 9

When i execute the command `ng build --prod`

I'am getting multiple errors on scss files similar to the following :

ERROR in Exceeded maximum budget for /Users/HASSEN/IdeaProjects/my-anuglar-project/src/app/navigation/sidenav-content/sidenav-content.component.scss. Budget 10 kB was not met by 51.9 kB with a total of 61.9 kB.

I don't want to increase the budget limit in the angular.json file because it's unreasonable since i didn't modify any of those scss files.

```
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "budgets": [
        {
          "type": "initial",
          "maximumWarning": "5mb",
          "maximumError": "6mb"
        },
        {
          "type": "anyComponentStyle",
          "maximumWarning": "6kb",
          "maximumError": "10kb"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: did your css grow, or did the limit got lower ? Could you show your `sidenav-content.component.scss` ? Does it have any import ?

Comment: @Random yes, it has an import of theme.css file which has the following import `@import '~@angular/material/theming';`
I guess then that the @angular/material/theming has grown, what to do in this situation ?

Comment: indeed, you should NOT include a theme in a component scss. Why do you import this file ? things like `mat-color($app-theme, primary)` ?

Comment: what is your angular-material version ?

Comment: the purpose of `@import '~@angular/material/theming';` is to include `@include mat-core();`
The material version is 9.2.4

Comment: the theme should not be included in a component SCSS. It should be imported in your styles.scss (or a distinct file, which is imported by your styles.scss)

Comment: So now i'am getting **Undefinded Variable** on $myvariable-primary defined in theme.scss and used in a component scss file => background-color:  mat-color($myvariable-primary);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254364/discussion-between-hassen-gaaya-and-random).